# SQL server Left join with child tables and get the table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume we have a table Instrument with child tables Equity and Bond having a foreign key InstrumentId. Each instrument has a unique record in one of the child tables.

Is it possible to make a view using left joins to see all the instrument with a column containing the table name in which the record is present ?

```
SELECT        Instrument.InstrumentId, Instrument.Name, ***CHILD_TABLE_NAME***
FROM          Instrument
LEFT OUTER JOIN
              Equity ON Equity.InstrumentId = Instrument.InstrumentId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
              Bond ON SBond.InstrumentId = Instrument.InstrumentId
```

An alternative is to make an union of inner joins:

```
SELECT instrumentId, Name, instrumentType 
FROM
(SELECT Instrument.instrumentId, Name, 'Equity' as instrumentType FROM dbo.Equity inner join Instrument on Instrument.InstrumentId = Equity.InstrumentId
UNION
SELECT Instrument.instrumentId, Name, 'Bond' as instrumentType from dbo.Bond inner join Instrument on Instrument.InstrumentId = Bond.InstrumentId) u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to include the table name in your joins like this

```
SELECT i.InstrumentId, 
       i.Name, 
       e.TableEquity,
       b.TableBond
FROM Instrument i 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select 'Equity' as TableEquity from Equity) e
    ON i.InstrumentId = e.InstrumentId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select 'Bond' as TableBond from Bond) b
    ON i.InstrumentId = b.InstrumentId
```

EDIT by @sofsntp : to merge the Equity/Bond in one column

```
SELECT i.InstrumentId, 
       i.Name, 
       (ISNULL(e.TableEquity,'') + ISNULL(b.TableBond ,''))
FROM Instrument i 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select *, 'Equity' as TableEquity from Equity) e
   ON e.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select *, 'Bond' as TableBond  from StraightBond) b
   ON b.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT i.InstrumentId, i.Name, 
       (CASE WHEN e.InstrumentId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Equity'
             WHEN b.InstrumentId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bond'
        END) as which_table
FROM Instrument i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Equity e
     ON e.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Bond b
     ON b.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId ;
```

Note:  This gives the *first* match.  If you want both:

```
SELECT i.InstrumentId, i.Name, 
       ((CASE WHEN e.InstrumentId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Equity' ELSE '' END) + 
        (CASE WHEN b.InstrumentId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Bond' ELSE '' END)
       ) as which_table
FROM Instrument i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Equity e
     ON e.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Bond b
     ON b.InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId ;
```

EDIT
I am adding END which was missing

Comment: Thank you will accept this as an answer. I fixed the syntax issue near the ELSE '') +